# How to get rid of PHP Undefined offset error?

Tags: php, arrays

How to get rid of error: `Undefined offset: 1 on line 20`? I know it occurs becaouse Im calling array that's offset simply does not exist.

Silecing it wiht @ just doesnt seem right at all.

```
//create an array with all x, y
for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) $array_x[] = $x;
for ($y = 1; $y <= 5; $y++) $array_y[] = $y;

$IN_x = "'" . implode("', '", $array_x) . "'";
$IN_y = "'" . implode("', '", $array_y) . "'";

$pullMapInfo = "SELECT x, y, value FROM mapinfo WHERE id='{$id}' AND x IN ({$IN_x}) AND y IN ({$IN_y})";
$pullMapInfo2 = mysql_query($pullMapInfo) or die('error here');

//create an associative array x, y => value
while ($pullMapInfo3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($pullMapInfo2)) {
    $result[ $pullMapInfo3['x'] ][ $pullMapInfo3['y'] ] = $pullMapInfo3['value'];
}

//loop to display output
foreach ($array_x as $x) {
foreach ($array_y as $y) {
    if (array_key_exists($x, $result) && array_key_exists($y, $result)) {
        echo '<div class="castle_array" id="'.$x,'x',$y.'">'. $result[$x][$y] .'</div>
                ';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="castle_array" id="'.$x,'x',$y.'"></div>
                ';
    }
}
}
```

2 for loops seems awkard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second call to `array_key_exists` should pass in `$result[$x]`:

```
if ( array_key_exists($x, $result) && array_key_exists($y, $result[$x]) ) {
    // Code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Um I dont really get why it shall be `($y, $result[$x])` instead of `($y, $result[$y])` or `($y, $result)`

Comment: @user1656447 - You want to check if the `$result[$x]` array has a `$y` key, since that's exactly what you're using on the very next line: `$result[$x][$y]`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
if (array_key_exists($x, $result) && array_key_exists($y, $result)) {
```

with:

```
if (isset($result[$x][$y])) {
```

Documentation: [isset](http://php.net/isset)

For Joseph Silber: Try [this PHP fiddle](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/0bg-vd4)

Comment: @JosephSilber: you are wrong. It is perfectly working. Check the examples on [the documentation page](http://php.net/isset) (specifically **Checking deeper array values**) and try it yourself.

Comment: @JosephSilber I added a PHP fiddle link to my answer, to prove my syntax is working and does not have to be changed as you think.